# Will the end of a background task trigger OnSuspending() event?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

The background task is not triggering OnSuspending() event every time. I have implemented some logic to write the state of the application in a file but that is not happening all the time.

I'm sorry, I can't share the client code.

Comment: The people who usually read minds and telepathically read code are on holidays at the moment. You will need explain your problem in a sufficient amount of detail with a minimal reproducible example, so normal people can understand the problem. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: You're not expected to share the client code, you're expected to share a minimal, reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: at a time two process or sate trying to write the same file that's why you got some application states log.

Comment: to overcome this try to add this state logs to database via webservices or any other way so that you will get all application sates

Comment: Hi, If you are debugging your application using Visual Studio, then please use the lifecycle events provided by VS, this is the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/app-lifecycle#app-terminate) about app lifecycle